# Are there any rules to have PC dragons in any palladium game?

Tags: character-creation, dragons, palladium-system

Are there any rules in one of the palladium books that would cover informations to create a PC dragon?

Comment: The Megaverse is pretty big. Do you mean for *Rifts*, *Heroes Unlimited*, the *Palladium Role-playing Game*, or something else?

Comment: regardless there. just where some rules are printed that lets one play a dragon (I would guess thus an RCC or how it is called)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Rifts* has enabled players to take the role of dragon hatchlings since the game's inception, and that game, given the vast amount of material available, remains Palladium's flagship dragon product. Different dragons appear in the game's [standard edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0916211509) and updated [*Ultimate Edition*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1574571508).

Rules for *dragon* dragons specific to the *Palladium Role-playing Game* are available in [*Dragons and Gods*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0916211983). As evidenced by the title, such dragons are typically inappropriate for player-characters, but it's Palladium. Talk to the GM.

At least one dragon (ported over from *Rifts*) exists in the *Heroes Unlimited* setting but that dragon's specifically a behind-the-scenes big bad. A generous GM may nonetheless allow such as a PC.

Comment: Also some more in Rift's Conversion Book, no? along with Chinese dragons in the China sourcebook.

Comment: @lly There are a host of dragons secreted in the various Palladium products, but the question was so broad it seemed to require only a general pointer in the right direction. I'd happily upvote a longer answer that provided a detailed list of playable Palladium dragons!